# How use height tag data in Project-OSRM?

Tags: srtm, osmosis, open-source-routing-machine

I am using Project-OSRM in my project .
All is works . But I need use elevation data. Downloaded osmosis master . And SRTM plugin added to osmosis. Also this worked fine . SRTM plugin started and I get new .osm file .
In test_with_srtm.osm file have height tag data. But I cannot see sad height tag information  in founded path json output format. 
Please, help me next steps.  How can I do it.  At least I want to see height tag data in retuned json result( https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-ba … utput-json ).

Answer (score 1):

Yep, thats about right. We haven't yet fully implemented outputting elevation profiles.

Comment: Any updates on the elevation profiles?